# Can I use an autoregressive (AR1) model to determine if longitudinal data can be treated as individual single time points?

Tags: regression, repeated-measures, linear-model, autoregressive

I am currently in a position where I have two datasets, one consisting of longitudinal data collected at 4 different time points, and another consisting of only single time points (e.g. data collected at the first time point only, and data collected at the second time point only etc.). It has come to my attention that I may not have enough statistical power using only the single time point data, but if I were to combine the single time point dataset with the longitudinal dataset, I may have enough power.

The concern I have is that this is a ill-advised procedure given that one is repeated measurements over time, and the other is not. The classic concerns regarding the repeated measurements is that the repeated exposure to the experimental condition would have skewed the measured responses not observed in the single time point dataset. From a statistical standpoint, the repeated measures means that the data is not independent as one subject could have multiple observations at different time points, and so their individual subject variability plays a larger role in the model being made  on the longutuidnal dataset. This feature would not be observed in the single time point dataset.

However, I have read about Autoregressive models (AR1) and I was wondering if AR1 models can be used to determine whether the repeated measures dataset (longitudinal dataset) can be treated as individual single time points since my understanding of AR1 models is that it can determine how well a past timepoint can predict the current one (given a t-1 observation, how well it predicts the t-th observation). If the AR1 model shows that there is no dependency (or low predictive ability), does that mean I can interpret that the longitudinal dataset can be essentially treated as single time point dataset (with regards to how the repeated exposure per subject has no effect)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a time series expert, but I don't think four time points is enough to estimate a AR(1) model. Usually, the label "time series" is for much longer time series. You could run correlations among the four time points, but I am not sure what that would do for you.  Your concern seems to be about a practice effect or exposure effect. You could model this in a couple ways; I am not sure which is best (and there may be other ways as well). But this is quite different from correlation among the points or from the dependency you propose modeling with AR(1).

You could look at the means at each time point and subtract the difference from the later time points.

You could add a variable for "data set" which would take levels "single point set", "first observation" and so on, and add this as a covariate.

But I would start with what is sometimes known as a "spaghetti plot" which each subject is a line, the y axis is the dependent variable, and the x-axis is time. This will show if there are strong patterns in the data and if the later time points are, somehow, biased.

Comment: Isn't the spaghetti plot essentially a visual representation of the data where if they are biased, there would be some linear regression that quantifies how correlated the dependent variable is with time?

Comment: The key question for you, I think, is not how _correlated_ the data are over time, but whether they increase. You could have very high correlation but no change, and that wouldn't be a problem. Or you could have relatively low correlation but a big increase, and that would be a problem.

Comment: If I was presented with a correlation matrix for both the longitudinal and single time point data, would it be my understanding to correlate the correlation matrix between longitudinal and single time point for every time point? Would this be a point-by-point correlation?